# Analysis: Show that there exists an $x$ so that $f'(x)=0$. (Derivative at point is equal to$ 0$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

Question: Look at already answered question.  Same.

Comment: Do you mean limits by $\rightarrow$?

Comment: Like converges to as we take s going to infinity

Comment: @kemb You may want to use $ \infty $ ;)

Comment: My bad, new to mathjax.  I'm not sure its necessarily saying that f(s)=0 at some point but that f(s) just goes to 0 taking s to be infinity.  Like for example, if f was 1/s.  f(s) goes to 0 as s goes to infinity but there is no point at which f(s)=0.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$?

Comment: Yes, I think that is more proper notation that I should have used.

Comment: You can do this by "condensing" the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$. For example, consider $g:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto f(\tan x)$.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by condensing the interval.

Comment: And is condensing the interval allowed in such a case?

Comment: @kemb See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is one-to-one, if not, we are done. Locally for $x=0$, we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that either $f(-\epsilon)<f(0)<f(\epsilon)$ or $f(-\epsilon)>f(0)>f(\epsilon)$, if not, apply Intermediate Value Theorem and we get a contradiction of being one-to-one. Assume that $f(-\epsilon)<f(0)<f(\epsilon)$. Interpolate another $\eta\in(0,\epsilon)$ such that $f(0)<f(\eta)<f(\epsilon)$. Now it is not hard to argue that $f(-x)<f(\epsilon)<f(0)<f(\eta)<f(x)$ for all $x\geq\epsilon$. Now taking $x\rightarrow\infty$ and we have $f(0)=f(\eta)=0$, a contradiction to being one-to-one.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that there exists an x show that f'(x)=0 directly.

Comment: Rolle Theorem is good. And my argument deduces that $f$ cannot be one-to-one, so Rolle Theorem now applies.

Comment: So after we deduce f cannot be one-to-one we can now apply Rolle's Theorem  because not being one-to one implies the endpoints are equal, f(a)=f(b) (but there are no endpoints as we are going from R to R?)?  We are already given differentiable, so also continuous.  So does that mean we can say there just exists an x so that f'(x)=0 by Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: If $f$ is not one-to-one, so $f(a)=f(b)$ for some distinct $a,b$, say, $a<b$. Then you just need to concentrate on $[a,b]$, and use Rolle Theorem to this interval, no need to bother what happens outside $[a,b]$.

Comment: Makes sense great, I get this part.

Comment: I was reading over your proof, I'm confused where you apply the Intermediate Value Theorem (not just where but how) and the steps where you say interpolate another.. and its not hard to argue that...  Thanks.

Comment: Now assume that $f(\epsilon)>f(0)$, what could possibly happen to $f(-\epsilon)$? If $f(-\epsilon)>f(0)$, and further assume that $f(-\epsilon)>f(\epsilon)$, then by IVT there is some $c\in(-\epsilon,0)$ such that $f(c)=f(\epsilon)$, then no good. Can you argue with the similar same way if $f(-\epsilon)<f(\epsilon)$? So we conclude that $f(-\epsilon)$ CANNOT $>f(0)$, so must be $<f(0)$, draw a picture always help, try that.

Comment: So if f(-e)<f(e) and f(0)<f(e), we have f(-e)<f(0)<f(e).  by IVT there exists n element of (0,e) that f(0)<f(n)<f(e).  Is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm confused could you just explain the other way too, thanks.

Comment: If $f(-\epsilon)<f(\epsilon)$ and $f(0)<f(\epsilon)$, you cannot deduce that $f(-\epsilon)<f(0)<f(\epsilon)$, you cannot simply insert and combine inequality, there is a simple counterexample. Anyway, I strongly recommend that you draw a picture, everything will be perfectly clear by picture, then argue with IVT.

Comment: And keep in mind that we have assumed that $f$ is one-to-one, if $f(\epsilon)>f(0)$, can you really draw a picture (with no jump or whatsoever) that $f(-\epsilon)>f(0)$? The fact that it cannot be so uses the argument of IVT.

Comment: The thing is I am confused by how this leads us to get a contradiction that its not one to one

Comment: At the very final of the reasoning we have found distinct numbers $0$ and $\eta$ but $f(0)=f(\eta)$, so this is not one-to-one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67993/discussion-between-user284331-and-kemb).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $g:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows
$$g(x):=
\begin{cases}
f(\infty), &x=\pi/2;\\
f(\tan x), &x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2);\\
f(-\infty), &x=-\pi/2.
\end{cases}
$$

Show that $g$ is continuous on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and differentiable on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Then apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: But for g(x),  g(a) does not equal g(b) so we can't apply Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Isn't it that $g(-\pi/2)=0=g(\pi/2)$?

Comment: I see.  Make sense.  This answer does seem complicated to me, to be honest, is there a simpler way to conceptualize the problem.  For example, I 'm not sure at all how to show g is continuous and differentiable on your interval.  Thanks though.

Comment: I don't know what you know about calculus. Assuming the standard theorems from mathematical analysis, these can be proved as follows: On $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, $g(x)$ is differentiable because it is the composition of two differentiable functions $f$ and $\tan$. Note that any differentiable function is continuous, so $g$ is continuous on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. To show that $g$ is continous on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, it suffices to show that $g(\pi/2)=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}g(x)=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(\tan x)$ and $g(-\pi/2)=\lim_{x\to-\pi/2}g(x)=\lim_{x\to-\pi/2}f(\tan x)$, which follows from the definition of $g$.

Comment: I see, I was thinking to prove it was continuous using epsilon delta definition, but I like your way better.  So now that we have g is continuous and differentiable and g(a)=g(b), we can apply Rolle's Theorem.  So that means there is a point c such that g'(c)=0.  However, aren't we supposed to show that there is some point x, so that f'(x)=0.

Comment: @kemb Well, the chain rule tells you how $g'(c)$ and $f'(c)$ are related.

Comment: So g'(x)=f'(tan(x)) *sec^2(x)

Comment: @kemb And $\sec x$ is nonzero.

Comment: Exactly.  So this implies f'(tan(c))=0.  Sorry for what may seem like a stupid question but does f'(tan(c))=0 imply f'(c)=0.

Comment: Oh, so basically on points on the curve tan(c) is where f'=0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67992/discussion-between-yuxiao-xie-and-kemb).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to simplify the problem first.  You're on the right track with Rolle's theorem.

First off, if $f(x) = 0$ there's nothing doing.  Now let's assume that the graph of $f$ even crosses the $x$ axis (it could only happen exactly once, or else you've got Rolle's).  We'd be done, right? Look at a point on the graph right above that zero crossing and draw a horizontal line.  As you venture towards one of ±infinity, you must come back below the line in order to approach zero.  You can formalize this to find $a,b$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$ and attack with Rolle's.

So now you can assume without loss of generality that the function never crosses the $x$ axis.  Maybe it looks something like a Gaussian, $e^{-x^2}$? You can use an argument much like above to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\equiv 0,$ we're done. So assume WLOG $f(a) > 0$ for some $a\in \mathbb R.$ Because $f\to 0$ at $\pm \infty,$ we can choose $b>0$ such that both $f(a+b),f(a-b)$ are less than $f(a).$ That implies the maximum value of $f$ on $[a-b,a+b]$ does not occur at an end point. Hence this maximum occurs at an interior point, where $f'=0.$